# Isolate scope variable is getting undefined inside link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that receives a data object and a function to it's isolate scope. In link function I'm declaring a scope method to trigger in a certain event (button click).

Problem is the value passed to the above mentioned method is available inside it, but the scope variable is still `undefined`.

Directive:

```
commentsModule.directive('commentsDirective', [ function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/alarm-viewer-comments-template.html',
            scope: {
                alarmComments: "=value",
                sendNewComment: "&sendNewComment"
            },
            link: function(scope, elems, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                scope.sendComment = function(data) {
                    console.log(scope.newComment);//this newComment variable is undefined
                    scope.sendNewComment(data);//data is correct
                    scope.newComment = '';
                };
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Here inside link function, `data` passed into `scope.sendComment` is available but yet `scope.newComment` gets `undefined`.
Template:

```
<h4>Comments</h4>
<div ng-repeat="comment in alarmComments.comments">
    <p>{{comment.timestamp}} | <strong>{{comment.user}}</strong>: {{comment.commentType}} {{comment.comment}}</p>
</div>
<div ng-if="alarmComments.editPermission && alarmComments.isActiveAlarm">
    <form name="commentsForm" role="form"  track-form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="newComment" pattern="/.{1,}" maxlength="4" required ng-enter="sendComment(newComment)"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="commentsForm.$invalid" ng-click="sendComment(newComment)">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

UI:

```
<comments-directive value="alarmComments" send-new-comment="addNewComment(comment)"></comments-directive>
```

Can someone help me out...?

edit: what I want is to clear the input text field after entering a comment.

Comment: can you provide [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) sample?

Comment: also what do `ng-enter` directive? seems like you confused it with `ng-keydown` and checking that press `enter` key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to debug problems like this is render scope ids (scope.$id) and verify they are of the same id.

Could you verify during link, what is the scope.$id and render it in your template?

```
<h4>Comments</h4>
<div ng-repeat="comment in alarmComments.comments">
<p>{{comment.timestamp}} | <strong>{{comment.user}}</strong>:   {{comment.commentType}} {{comment.comment}}</p>
</div>
 <div ng-if="alarmComments.editPermission && alarmComments.isActiveAlarm">
<form name="commentsForm" role="form"  track-form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newComment" pattern="/.{1,}" maxlength="4" required ng-enter="sendComment(newComment)"/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="commentsForm.$invalid" ng-click="sendComment(newComment)">Send</button>
{{$id}}
</form>
</div>
```

Sometimes templates create its own scope and you might have to use $parent.newComment in your templates.

Answer (score 1):

Within directive scope you should map the `newComment` property also along with `alarmComments`. like below -

```
scope: {
    alarmComments: "=value",
    newComment: "=newComment",
    sendNewComment: "&sendNewComment"
},
```

Comment: I tried, but still it's getting undefined. also I tried newComment: "=?newComment" but no luck.